# Finding docs that do not contain a given user in all nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping for a nested field called ratings:

```
"ratings" : {
  "type" : "nested",
  "properties" : {
    "rating" : {
      "type" : "double"
    },
    "user_id" : {
      "type" : "long"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to find all records where a user_id does not exist in the nested field.

Here's what I have, but it's failing when there are multiple nested docs and any of the docs are not user_id 1.

```
{
"nested": { 
    "path": "ratings", 
    "query": { 
         "bool": { "must_not": [
             { "term": { "ratings.user_id": 1}}
]}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and what you are trying to do is find documents for which NONE of the nested documents have a specific `user_id`, then this query seems to do what you want (assuming you want docs that have not been rated by user `2`):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "not": {
               "filter": {
                  "nested": {
                     "path": "ratings",
                     "filter": {
                        "term": {
                           "ratings.user_id": 2
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/afd319e64403a7f995cbf1e9f40e5c5948729193